# Suppose the characteristic polynomial is $x^4$. Is it possible to get a jordan block of size$ J(2)J(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Suppose the characteristic polynomial is $x^4$. Is it possible to get a jordan block of size $ J(2)J(2)$?

This would mean that I get $2$ vectors in the eigenspaces, but then it seems like an impossible task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean 
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr} \ ?$$
What seems impossible?

Comment: How would I get this? I mean it would be possible if eigenvalues were distinct, but $x^4$ forces an eigenvalue of $0$ with multiplicity $4$, so I thought I can only get a combination of $J(3)$ and $J(1)$

Comment: @GRS It depends on your minimal polynomial. Your $J(3)$ and $J(1)$ is only possible with minimal polynomial $\mu_A(x) = x^3$. For $J(2)$ and $J(2)$ we need $\mu_A(x) = x^2$.

Comment: What do you think is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix I wrote?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm not sure, seems like $x^4$ but you rearranged the columns of the vectors

Comment: No, I didn't rearrange anything.  What I wrote is a Jordan form with two blocks $J(2)$ and $J(2)$.   The characteristic polynomial is easy to see, since the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is ...

Answer (score 2):

The possibilities are $$J(1),J(1),J(1),J(1)$$ if the minimal polynomial is $x$, or $$J(2),J(1),J(1) \quad \textrm{ or} \quad J(2),J(2)$$ if the minimal polynomial is $x^2$, or $$J(3),J(1)$$ if the minimal polynomial is $x^3$, or $$J(4)$$ if the minimal polynomial is $x^4$.

Notice that all of these are possibilities since you could just write down any of these matrices and you would have a matrix whose Jordan form is what you were asking for.

For instance $$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is a matrix whose Jordan form (is itself) is of the form $J(3),J(1)$.

And the matrix in Robert's response has Jordan form of type $J(2),J(2)$.

Comment: You may or may not be familiar with elementary divisors, but they are invariants that are powers of irreducible divisors of the characteristic polynomial. For each irreducible divisor, if you take the highest power of it that shows up as an elementary divisor, and then take the product of these, you get the minimal polynomial. The size and number of Jordan blocks are exactly determined by the elementary divisors. Therefore if you want a Jordan form of type $J(2),J(2)$, you need the elementary divisors of your matrix to be $x^2$ and $x^2$. So the minimal polynomial must be $x^2$.